# NSSortDescriptor doesn't work for all attributes from CoreData

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have one problem with my table. I've made CoreData attribute1,2,3 where user can store NSStrings. This data i show in TableView with sortDescriptorWithKey: "attribute1". Then i have three buttons over my table, where user can manually change this description by taping on them. When he want arrange data by attribute1 or attribute2 everything work fine, but attribute3 doesn't work. Data in table are sorted by chaos.

Any help appreciated.

here is my code for these buttons:

```
-(IBAction)sortTable:(UIButton*)sender {
 NSString *key = @"price";
 if (sender.tag ==1) {
    key = @"date";
 } else if (sender.tag ==2) {
    key = @"result";
 } 
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Data"];
request.sortDescriptors =
@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:key ascending:NO]];
self.mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Is attribute3 transient?

Comment: No .. All attributes are optional. No transient.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Make sure you are actually displaying the `attribute3` string in your table and not something else. Cross check with your data in the actual sqlite store.

Still, I think your code is quite redundant. Try to simplify. One way is to have your buttons have the tags 1, 2, and 3.

```
-(IBAction)sortTable:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"attribute%d", sender.tag];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:"Data"];
    request.sortDescriptors = 
       @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:key ascending:NO]];
    self.mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
       [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Hey Mundi. You are trying help me again? :) i will try change my code, but attribute1,2,3 was just example. i have another names in my code, so i can't use tags. Just if i implement "if" statements with this tags.

Comment: Did you check the values in the price field? Also, not that you should jut use `key = @"date";` not `stringWithFormat`. and drop the `alloc`, it is enough to do `NSString *key;`.

Comment: But attribute3 is "price". So how about the price values? Did you check them?

Comment: Yes. When i click on some cell, show me detail info with all attributes in next ViewController. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: That string i store to that attribute from label. It is simple calculation between two textfield and show result in that label. It can be problem for descriptor? Is it double value saved as string.